# How to draw border for a group of division in a GeoJSON file in python?

Tags: python, geojson

I use following code to  read a geoJSON file and which is working. GeoJSONN file contains multiple divisions of the map and each of them have a group name in  the file.

I could add gray border  to each of these  divisions. Now I want to add another red color border to groups of divisions which has the same group name, and show the group name in the middle of group. How can I do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from descartes import PolygonPatch
import simplejson as json

json_data = []
with open('LKA_adm2-2.json') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3.841, 7.195), dpi=100)
ax = fig.gca()

for section in json_data["features"]:

#multiple sections will have same group_name.  
#based on this name I want to create a collection of sections and draw a border for it.

    group_name = section["properties"]["NAME"]
    ax.add_patch(PolygonPatch(section["geometry"], fc="#ffffff", ec='#9C9C9C', alpha=1, zorder=2, lw=0.2 ))

plt.show()
```

PS: Groups are always adjacent